# Why is a blocked user showing up in my watchdog logs?

Tags: users, log-messages

Upon checking my error logs in watchdog today, I discovered an IP address that tried to go to a (non-existent) admin page. I have already blocked this IP and when I go to https://example.com/admin/user/rules/check and type in the IP address, I get the message 
[image]